# Is it possible to group 3D shapes in BABYLON.js

Tags: javascript, babylonjs

In **Flash as3** we can create `DisplayObject` and add them to a `DisplayObjectContainer` so that all the transformations applied to the parent container will be effected to the children also. Similarly in **Phaser** we can group the shapes using **Phaser.Group**. Is it possible to do the similar thing in **BABYLON.js** for the 3D Shapes. I know that it is possible to merge meshes using `MeshBuilder.MergeMeshes(meshes, disposeSource, allow32BitsIndices, meshSubclass)`
Is there any other simple method to group 3D shapes in BABYLON.js?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Babylon supports constructing a scene graph trough setting the parent of an object. For example, from the tutorial on [position/rotation/scaling](http://doc.babylonjs.com/tutorials/Position,_Rotation,_Scaling),

```
//Positioning box3 relative to box1
box3.parent = box1;
box3.position.z = -10;
```

This allows for hierarchical grouping. Howerver, if there is no explicit parent to your group the only option seems to be to create a dummy mesh and make it invisible.